# Assert error about Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, assert

When I try to assert the result of my drag and drop(offset x and y), I see this error message:

[image]

My code:

```cs
var sourceStartLocation = sourceStart.Location;
IWebElement target = driver.FindElement(By.Id("droppablerevert"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
string classBefore = target.GetAttribute("class");

builder.DragAndDrop(sourceStart, target).Perform();

IWebElement fullTarget = driver.FindElement(By.Id("droppablerevert"));
string classAfter = fullTarget.GetAttribute("class");

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

IWebElement sourceEnd = driver.FindElement(By.Id("draggablerevert"));
var sourceEndLocation = sourceEnd.Location;

Assert.AreNotEqual(classBefore, classAfter);        
Assert.AreEqual(sourceStartLocation, sourceEndLocation);
```

Comment: Find a location for a droppable element using get a location use this :                      int x = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ext-comp-1271")).getLocation().getX(); int y = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ext-comp-1271")).getLocation().gety();

Comment: I would try to make the drag and drop action in javascript